# OSIF USB->TWI/I2C

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Community,

is anybody using the OpenSource OSIF with ROS ?
OSIF is a hardware USB interface for TWI/I2C sensors.

Regards
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9595/osif-usb-%3Etwi/i2c/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think that any work has been done on this, but there seems to be something that you could use as a starting point over here: https://sites.google.com/site/lvmarcoux/Home/osi

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2011-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0